# Which is the best approach to initialize an Interface. (Activity-Frament)?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am new to the world of Android Programming,Here is my question.

Suppose I've an Activity named `A` and a Fragment named `F`. I know that the interaction between `Activity` and `Fragment` should be done through an `Interface`. I used to set the `Interface` in the `onAttach()` of `Fragment` like this

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mListener = (MyListenerInterface) activity;
}
```

and now am heard about the `Static Factory Method` from [here](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/using-newinstance-to-instantiate.html). 
My question is :  **Which is the best approach to init. a listener ? `onAttach()` method or initialize the listener through the static factory method ,like this?**.

```
public static MyFragment newInstance(MyListenerInterface mListener) {
        MyFragment f = new MyFragment();
        this.mListener = mListener;
        ...........
        return f;
}
```

I think, it is better to initialize  the listener through the `static factory method` instead of casting from the activity,so we could avoid a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you do not need to cast anything via factory, but `onAttach` is better in my opinion because you have less chance of leaking an activity context. Let's say you make an instance with the factory and never use that fragment, it will leak the context of the Activity and there by everything in it. Also don't forget to destroy the interface in the `onDetach`.

Also you can have many instances of that fragment and with option one, they will all have the same listener, not good.

Also you should make what you could call a `BaseActivity`, an abstract activity all other extend from and define the interface methods there and you will avoid always casting to a lot of different classes. This will also come in handy if you need to quickly change something in every activity of your app.

Comment: what is implied by `don't forget to destroy the interface in the onDetach` ? null ? Is it must for every `onAttach` ?

Comment: onDetach you should set listenerInteface = null so you don't cause any leaks.

Answer (score 1):

First option  (Initializing the listener in the `OnAttach()`) is a better one because

- In first option the `MyListenerInterface` is an non-static variable, so each fragment has its own listener.
- Whereas the second option's `MyListenerInterface` variable is an static that is reference maintained at the class level and  common for all the other fragment instances this causes the problem when you need the same fragment in different activity then the listener of one activity will be overrided with another activity.